# Pointers of strings == NULL?

Tags: c, string, cs50

Just watching lectures of cs50, that is from one about Memory. And this version of programm was not in the lection itself, but only in source code for lection. Final version during lesson was without those two conditions if (t != NULL) and if (s != NULL).

```
// Capitalizes a copy of a string without memory errors

#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Get a string
    char *s = get_string("s: ");
    if (s != NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Allocate memory for another string
    char *t = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (t != NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Copy string into memory
    strcpy(t, s);

    // Capitalize copy
    t[0] = toupper(t[0]);

    // Print strings
    printf("s: %s\n", s);
    printf("t: %s\n", t);

    // Free memory
    free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

What`s the actual point of that

```
if (s != NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

How can s even be NULL? Shouldn`t that stop programm in every case? What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 2):

after

> ```
> if (s != NULL)
> {
>     return 1;
> }
> ```

you use *s* supposing it it *not* NULL doing `strlen(s)` then `strcpy(t, s)` etc, so you want

```
if (s == NULL)
{
    return 1;
}
```

You have exactly the same problem with

> ```
> if (t != NULL)
> {
>    return 1;
> }
> ```

*t* is null in case there is not enough memory to do the allocation, and in that case you do not want to continue else `strcpy(t, s);` has an undefined behavior, so you want

```
 if (t == NULL)
 {
    return 1;
 }
```

> How can s even be NULL?

As indicated in the description of `get_string` : *Returns NULL upon error or no input whatsoever (i.e., just EOF).*

So one way is to launch your program redirecting `stdin` from an empty file.

> Shouldn`t that stop programm in every case?

no, *s* and *t* can be NULL or not NULL, they are not always NULL nor always not NULL.

Note the input string can be empty, in that case the behavior is defined but the interest is limited, *s* and *t* being an empty string.